# Should i use std::string in a web server for parsing a client request?

Tags: c++, http, sockets, parsing, server

I'm coding a little HTTP 1.1 web server in *C++98* (c++ version mandated by my school) and i haven't make a decision about which data type i'm gonna use to perform the request parsing, and how.

Since i'll be receiving **read-only** (by read-only i mean that i don't have to modify the buffer) data from a user-agent, would it make sense to use std::string to store the incoming data ?

- HTTP syntax is very straightforward, and can be parse using a finite state machine. Iterating over a `const char *` seems enough and doesn't make any allocations, i can use buffer that recv gives me.
- On the other hand, i could use `std::string` facilities like `find` and `substr` to parse the request, but that would lead to memory allocations.

My server doesn't need to be as efficient as nginx, but i'm still worried about the performance of my application.

I'm eager to know your thoughts.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) but unfortunately that is a C++17 feature.  For processing c-style strings, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring

Comment: `std::string` can be trivially converted to `const char*` with `c_str()` meaning you lose absolutely nothing by using it, and gain a whole lot of protection against buffer overflows.

Comment: Remember a common trick to attack a service is to keep sending data. Be sure you eventually cut off the request at some reasonably high limit, like 1GB or something, to avoid crashing out for lack of memory.

Comment: Yes, a defined maximum header lenght is required. About using 20th century C++ compiler : i'm using modern clang compiler with the `-std=c++98` flag.

Comment: (1) HTTP is not simple at all, if you want to implement it fully. For example are you going to support WebSockets? Are you gonna implement chunked encoding? Compression? Are you even aware how complicated HTTP/1.1 is? Because this claim is hilarious. (2) Requests and responses can be arbitrarily big. In paractice you can't avoid allocations. (3) Analysing string through functions like `find` and/or `substr` is insanely inefficient. In practice you would do manual traversal and char-by-char analysis.

Comment: Hi, as stated, this is a "little" web server. What claim are you talking about ?
Reading the RFC, i'm aware how complex HTTP/1.1 is. Because this is a school project, we're only restricted to implement just a few methods like `GET` `POST` and `DELETE`. As of chunked encoding, the RFC state that a receipt must be able decode chunked request. This is a very lightweight implementation, and will support the bare minimum of a HTTP/1.1 compliant server.

Comment: @Noctuelles  About using -std=c++98...   The problem is that we are now in the 21st century.  Almost a quarter of the way through the 21st century, to be more precise.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Ikr... My school says that you've to learn how to walk before flying planes. And it makes sense, at least for a few cases : we had to implement `vector`, `map`, and we were glad that we were restricted to `c++98`. This our last project using `c++98`, after that, we're free to use modern cpp.

Comment: @freakish i was talking about the syntax of HTTP :) Claiming that HTTP has a simple syntax is not hilarious, but claiming HTTP is a simple protocol and writing compliant web server is easy, is hilarious, and i never made such claim.

Comment: @Noctuelles I'm not exactly sure what you perceive as syntax and what as protocol. But lets not dwell on that. The point is that this task is hard. Parsing itself, and we didn't even start talking about networking and millions of edge cases that have to be handled. Even in a small subset of HTTP this won't be an easy task. So it makes me wonder: is that task your own idea or given by school? Because if it is your idea, then I strongly recommend you choose something else, before you rage quit in frustration. XD

Comment: @freakish Given by school: [subject](https://cdn.intra.42.fr/pdf/pdf/65347/en.subject.pdf)

Comment: @Noctuelles I feel sorry for you. Seriously, this task is a nightmare. They not only want you to write an HTTP server from scratch, but also a non-blocking variant. They basically want you to reimplement nginx. They should pay you for doing this. And additionally for bad working environment because of C++98. It still amazes me how unreal schools are.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Noctuelles I understand the thing about walking before flying a plane...  But in the end,  how much walking do you have to do while flying a plane?  In the end, snce going from point A to point B looks like walking, you may end up doing a lot of walking for simple stuff that only require a small flying hop.  Watch out for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely. It's a school project, not a high-performance production server (in which case you'd be using a more modern C++ variant).

The biggest performance problem you'd typically have with `std::string` is not parsing, but string building. `a + b + c + d + e` can be rather inefficient. Details, really: just start by writing a correct implementation, and then see which parts are too slow in testing. There are very few projects, even in commercial software development, where that's not the right approach.